# Windows / Intel Compiler / Inline Assembler & GNU syntax problems

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, intel

I have this C snippet, which gives a compiler error and I don't have a clue why:

```
// compiler dependent inline assemble 
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
#define ASM __asm
#else
#define ASM __asm__
#endif

int getfpucw(
    /* Get FPU control word */
) {
    int mode = 0;

  // load mode value into register %0, no output ...: :...
    ASM fnstcw *&mode;
    ASM("fnstcw %0" : "m"(*&mode));
    return mode;
}
```

I get:

> ../src/fpucw.c(28): error: invalid constant in assembly language
>   instruction
>           ASM("fnstcw %0" : : "m"(*&mode));
>               ^
>
> ../src/fpucw.c(28): error: invalid constant in assembly language
>   instruction
>           ASM("fnstcw %0" : : "m"(*&mode));

The first ASM statement gets thru. I think because it's MS ASM syntax?

However, I want to avoid, to always use #ifdef around ASM statements as we use GCC as well.

Comment: Is your code written in C or is it written in C++? Please choose at most one of the two languages.

Comment: Inline assembly is compiler-specific. If you want to avoid a bunch of ifdefs, don't use inline assembly. Put the assembly code in assembly files instead, and assemble them with the same assembler regardless of which C compiler you're using.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you show us the generated assembly please?

Comment: And note that as you write to the operand, it needs to be an output operand, not an input operand. So write `ASM("fnstcw %0" : "m"(mode))` instead. Possibly this also fixes your other issues.

Comment: That's not C code.

Comment: Also, check if you have intrinsics for fetching the control word without using assembly ... what do you need it for anyway?

Comment: The code we use the ASM in is pure C.

Comment: What we do is, setting the FPU into extended precision mode.

Comment: ASM("fnstcw %0" : "m"(mode)) - Ups, sorry, that's right. But I still get the same errors.

Comment: @RobertM.Münch What do you try to achieve by doing this? If you use the `long double` type in your code, the compiler should automatically emit code to switch the fpu to extended precision mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what your problem is: You have `ASM` directives for both MSVC-style and gcc-style assembly, but you always include both of them. Of course, icc is confused by a gcc-style `asm` directive and vice versa. To fix this problem, I recommend to re-define `ASM` like this:

```
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
#define IASM(x) __asm x
#define GASM(x) 
#else
#define IASM(x)
#define GASM(x) __asm__(x)
#endif
```

and then change your asm-directives:

```
IASM(fnstcw *&mode);
GASM("fnstcw %0" : : "m"(*&mode));
```

Lastly note that for the gcc-style assembly directive to work properly, `mode` must be an output operand as you overwrite its value. Thus change that line to:

```
GASM("fnstcw %0" : "=m"(mode));
```

and note that the  `*&` is redundant and can be omitted.

Comment: Although Intel's compiler can support either GCC-style or MSVC-style inline assembly syntax for compatibility reasons, you *almost certainly* want to use the GCC-style syntax because it is so much more powerful (and you're writing it anyway!). MSVC's syntax offers no way to specify input values, so it always does a bunch of extra stores and loads.

Comment: I added the MSVC style just to see if it works this way, as said, ICC supports both. I would like to go with GCC style.

Comment: @RobertM.Münch Can you show me the generated assembly please? It might be that you need to use Intel syntax for ICC. Luckily, there is a way to specify both AT&T and Intel assembly in a gcc-style asm statement.